# connecting to remote database with jdbc, verify credentials

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am getting a java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found. I am trying to connect to a remote database. I think I have all my credentials correct.

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql:sshhost/db1";
    try {
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "usr", "");
        Statement myStat = myConn.createStatement();
        ResultSet myRs = myStat.executeQuery("select * from students");
        while (myRs.next()) {
            System.out.println(myRs.getString("last_name") + ", " + myRs.getString("first_name"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The host is the same remote host that I ssh into. 
I log on to mysql as `root` and this requires no password so I left the last parameter `""`
The database I want to use while logged into root is called `db1`.
I'm not sure if my parameters are valid.

Comment: I think you're missing the mysql connector/j jar on your classpath; that's what the no suitable driver message means.

Comment: Keep in mind that the database username and password aren't necessarily the same as your Linux password.

Comment: @Tim I am changing things around but not I get `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'username'@'%' to database 'db1'
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)` I think I am getting confused to what are the correct credentials... it's driving me crazy

Comment: Figure out your database credentials first, by connecting (outside of your program) using something like SQLPlus.  Once you know them, it should be simple to configure JDBC to use them.

Comment: Also, your new error message implies that you got past the "No suitable driver found" exception; what did you change to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You have not loaded a driver. JDBC need to have a driver loaded before a connection can be made. So make sure you load an apt driver class using:

```
Class.forName("driverClass");
```

If you are using Java 6 or above(which included JDBC 4), you don't need the above mentioned dynamic driver class loading.

In both the cases, make sure the driver class you are using is present in your classpath.

Comment: I'm new to this JDBC sorry. I'm still not quite sure what this means. I have added a dependency for connector/j in my pom.xml but that is about it

Comment: I thought that in JDBC 4.0, calling `Class.forName()` was no longer necessary.  [Source](http://www.onjava.com/2006/08/02/jjdbc-4-enhancements-in-java-se-6.html)

Comment: @Tim  Yes you are right, post Java 6, which includes JDBC 4 ,does not require explicit driver loading. Updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: Note, it requires the driver impl to support the auto-loading.  so simply using java 6+ isn't enough.  i would imagine most modern drivers are updated, but you never know...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update your classpath to point to the mysql jar file.  The JVM can't find a suitable mysql driver.

Comment: I currently have connector/j in my pom.xml. I thought that was enough but I guess I am wrong.`        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: Driver is not loaded using dynamic class loading. It is required before a connection can be established.